# multi-level array in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

how can I form a multi-level array in Jquery.
Here's what I have, but I'm sure im in the wrong way

```
newTutorial[0]['header'] = 'some header';
newTutorial[0]['text'] = 'some text';

newTutorial[1]['header'] = 'some header';
newTutorial[1]['text'] = 'some text';

...
```

and I need such thing for more than 17 elements

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood your question correctly, then you can do something like following

```
var times = 17; // you can define times over here 


for (var i = 0 ; i < times; i++) {
    newTutorial[i]['header'] = 'some header';
    newTutorial[i]['text'] = 'some text';

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just with `do-while` loop

```
var i=0;
do {
    newTutorial[i]['header'] = 'some header';
    newTutorial[i]['text'] = 'some text';
    i++;
}
while (i < 17);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert same value in each `Index` then you can do as following:

```
var newTutorial = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
  newTutorial[i] = new Array();//need to define array at each index
  newTutorial[i]['header'] = 'some header';
  newTutorial[i]['text'] = 'some text';
}
```